# Change Active Seat without Model closing and opening again in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, modal-dialog

when i select a different seat number model closes and opens again how can in fix this

```
    const handleClick = (number) => {
    setIsActive(number);
    };

    const seats = Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={i+1}
          style={isActive == i+1 ? styles.activecircle : styles.circle}
          onPress={() => handleClick(i+1)}
        >
          <Text>{i+1}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ));
  

    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
    <Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={true}
    visible={isVisible}
    onRequestClose={onClose}>
        <View style={styles.noofseat}>
            {seats}
        </View>
    </View>
   </Modal>
```

[image: modal photo]

I want that modal dont reopens as anyone change no. of seat and active seat changes smoothly

Comment: Can you expand your code snippet to include the handlers for changing the isVisible variable and the setIsActive function.

Comment: move isVisible variable to useRef without useState.